# Intersecting lines in Python

Tags: python

```
from pylab import polyfit, polyval, plot, grid, xlabel, ylabel, show

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y1 = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 9]
x2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y2 = [8, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]

m1, b1 = polyfit(x1, y1, 1)
yp1 = polyval([m1, b1], x1)
plot(x1, yp1)

m2, b2 = polyfit(x2, y2, 1)
yp2 = polyval([m2, b2], x2)
plot(x2, yp2)

plot(x1, yp1)
plot(x2, yp2)
grid(True)
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

I am trying to do two linear fits for some data on the same graph with the above code. The lines of best fit happen to intersect and I am interested in that intersection point. How can I get that point from python and then plot it on the graph?

In other words I want to put a big fat circle where `yp1` and `yp2` intersect and print that value.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that is runnable *on its own*, meaning all imports are included and all variables are defined. We have no idea where your functions are coming from or what your data looks like.

Comment: What are `polyfit`, `polyval`, and `plot`?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I deserve that. I have updated to a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple mathematical problem and is not really specific to Python.

You have 2 equations and two unknowns (the ordinate, `xs` and coordinate `ys` of the point where both lines intersect).

```
ys = m1 * xs + b1 
ys = m2 * xs + b2
```

You can put that in matrix form, to get a system of equations, which you can then solve for easily with `numpy.linalg.solve`.

The transformation involves reordering the terms of these equations, e.g. like this:

```
m1 * xs - 1 * ys = - b1
m2 * xs - 1 * ys = - b2
```

The matrix formulation should now become apparent:

```
⎧m1 -1⎫   ⎧xs⎫    ⎧ -b1 ⎫
|     | . |  |  = |     |
⎩m2 -1⎭   ⎩ys⎭    ⎩ -b2 ⎭
```

This is easily solved with libraries that perform linear algebra, such as `numpy.linalg` (a subset of what you're importing).

```
import numpy # part of pylab but I prefer loading specific modules, not a whole blob
# matrix form: A * X = B
A = numpy.array([[m1, -1], [m2, -1]])
B = numpy.array([[-b1], [-b2]])
# notice that X is simply a column vector: array([[xs],[ ys]])
xs,ys = numpy.linalg.solve(A,B)

# final step, plot the point of intersection with e.g. a black single dot:
plt.plot(xs, ys, 'ko ')
```

For more information on solving systems of linear equations, I suggest refreshing your knowledge by reading any basic maths book. [A primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) is also given on wikipedia, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in solving this problem using Python, I suggest the [scikit-spatial](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

```py
from skspatial.objects import Line

x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y1 = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 9]
x2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y2 = [8, 7, 8, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1]

xy_1  = list(zip(x1, y1))
xy_2  = list(zip(x2, y2))

line_best_fit_1 = Line.best_fit(xy_1)
line_best_fit_2 = Line.best_fit(xy_2)

intersection_point = line_best_fit_1.intersect_line(line_best_fit_2)
```